# Delphi: how to show trayicon balloon without showing taskbar when set to autohide

Tags: delphi, taskbar, trayicon

How can I avoid the taskbar popping up when set to autohide, when using ShowBalloonHint?

Comment: The question and title are simple enough to understand the issue. Set your taskbar to autohide, then use a TrayIcon in your program and call ShowBaloonHint, the taskbar will come out of auto-hide.

Comment: So you want your balloon notifications to not behave like standard Windows balloon notifications? Then don't use the standard Windows balloon notifications, and create your own. If that's too much work, accept that some behaviour is not adjustable.

Comment: "then what's the point of the existence of this website?" It is meant to supplement websearch rather than replace it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification area in Windows has a defined behavior. You can wish it behaved differently, but that doesn't change the fact that what you want to do cannot be done.

Sorry for the inconvience.

---

A close workaround would be to create a `TOOLTIP` window yourself, and position it on the screen near where you think the user's notification area might be:

- bottom right
- top right
- bottom left
- primary monitor
- secondary monitor

That will involve using

- `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN)`
- `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN)`
- `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA)`

Then you create a `TOOLTIPS_CLASS` window:

```
    FHandle := CreateWindow(TOOLTIPS_CLASS, PChar(''),
            WS_POPUP or TTS_BALLOON,
            Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT), Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT),
            Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT), Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT),
            0, 0, HInstance,
            nil);
```

Then you would send it the `TTM_SETTITLE`, `TTM_UPDATETIPTEXT`, `TTM_TRACKPOSITION` messages, and finally the big moment: `TTM_TRACKACTIVATE`:

[image]

And then sometime later you hide the tooltip with another call to `TTM_TRACKACTIVATE`.

---

You're free to [follow Windows user experience guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx), or you can roll your own.